# .htaccess RewriteRule and Redirect conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, conflict

Have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?module=PageView&page_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And this redirects

```
Redirect 301    /shops/ /magaziny
Redirect 301    /contact    /kontakty
Redirect 301    /about /o-nas
Redirect 301    /kakkupit   /kak-kupit
```

They conflicts with each other and for example when I go to http://domain.do/shops/
I have:

```
http://domain.do/magaziny?module=PageView&page_url=shops
```

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a condition to your RewriteRule so that it won't execute if shops, contact, about or kakkupit is in the url. It would look something like this:

```
Redirect 301    /shops/ /magaziny
Redirect 301    /contact    /kontakty
Redirect 301    /about /o-nas
Redirect 301    /kakkupit   /kak-kupit

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(shops|contact|about|kakkupit)\b
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?module=PageView&page_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution not work.
may be it make some sense - this site use simpla cms

Comment: It does work (I have tested it), but most likely the redirect is cached in your browser and you forgot to clear your cache. Clear that cache, or test it in a different browser. For future tests, **always use 302 or temporary redirects** to prevent that problem.

Comment: shame on me, i forget about cash..
so this really work, thanks a lot